# Is possible to ignore the TextBox?

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I'm creating a program to calculate the average. There are 12 TextBox and I want to create the possibility to leave some fields blank. Now there are only errors and the crash of the program. Is possible to create that?

This is part of code:

```
ItalianoScritto = (TextBox1.Text)
MatematicaScritto = (TextBox2.Text)
IngleseScritto = (TextBox3.Text)
InformaticaScritto = (TextBox4.Text)
ScienzeScritto = (TextBox5.Text)
FisicaScritto = (TextBox6.Text)
MediaScritto = (ItalianoScritto + MatematicaScritto + IngleseScritto + InformaticaScritto + ScienzeScritto + FisicaScritto) / 6
Label10.Text = Str(MediaScritto)
```

If i leave blank the textbox1 when I click on the button to calculate the average Vb says **Cast not valid from the string "" to type 'Single'** and the bar of te textbox1 become yellow

Comment: What does the code that crashes look like, and in what way does it crash? Also, some tips on writing good questions: http://tinyurl.com/sohints

Comment: It says:
Cast not valid from the string "" to type 'Single'.

Comment: What is the datatype of the variables xxxxxScritto? You are freely passing string values ​in potentially numeric variables without any check. Do you have OPTION STRICT ON?

Answer (score 2):

I would do the following:
Iterate over the textboxes and check if you can parse the value into an iteger. If yes, add it to a value list.
Then add all values from that list and divide it by the number of cases.
It is faster than big if-statements and resilient against error

```
dim TBList as new list(of Textbox)
'add your textboxes to the list here
TbList.add(Textbox1)
...

dim ValList as new List(Of Integer)
for each elem in Tblist
  dim value as integer
  If integer.tryparse(elem.text,value)=True
    ValList.add(Value)
  else
    'report error or do nothing
  end if
next

dim Result as Integer
Dim MaxVal as Integer =0
for each elem in ValList 
  Maxval +=elem
next

Result = MaxVal / ValList.count
```

If you need support for point values, just choose double or single instead of Integer.
Also: regardless what you do -CHECK if the values in the textboxes are numbers or not. If you omit the tryparse, somebody will enter "A" and your app will crash and burn

Also: You OPTION STRICT ON!

Answer (score 0):

You just have to check if the `TextBox` is blank on each one before using the value:

```
If TextBox7.TextLength <> 0 Then
    'Use the value inside
End If
```

The way to do it depends a lot of your code. You should consider editing your question giving more information (and code) in order to us to help you better.